# php array echo if statement

Tags: php, arrays, if-statement

I have the following php echo:

```
<?php echo $tag->title; ?>
```

It pulls 4 multiple items, i.e.

A
B
C
D

I what to add an IF stateement to the above code so that:

IF A - echo A or

IF B - echo B or

IF C - echo C or

IF D - echo NOTHING

Comment: Does it echo `A B C D` in one go? or in a loop?

Comment: hi there... yes, it echo's all in one go

Comment: What's your question? Add an if (or switch in that case)

Comment: It pulls 4 multiple items? unable to get this..please explain

Comment: Most probably there is a loop around that statement, can you paste the line above and below that echo?

Comment: `<? echo $tag->title=='D'?'NOTHING':$tag->title; ?>` is this what you want ?

Comment: $tag->title; is a string "A B C D"?

Comment: Please elaborate on your question and tell us what you actually want to achieve. Might be work looking at the difference between 'echo' and 'print' however, because the latter works as a function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your string all in one like `A B C D`, you can `explode` them

```
$exp = explode(" ", $tag->title);

if(in_array("A", $exp)) echo "A";
if(in_array("B", $exp)) echo "B";
if(in_array("C", $exp)) echo "C";
if(in_array("D", $exp)) echo "NOTHING";
```

Answer (score 1):

try Switch case

```
<?php
switch ($tag->title) {
    case "A":
        echo "A";
        break;
    case "B":
        echo "B";
        break;
    case "C":
        echo "C";
        break;
    case "D":
        echo "NOTHING";
        break;
}
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can write this:

```
<?php echo $tag->title; 

if($tag[`0`]==`A`)
{
echo `A`;
}

?>
```

Comment: I don't know if it's because you don't know how to format your answers for this site or what, but you know that backticks in PHP have special meaning.

Answer (score 0):

You could use the [ternary operator](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php):

```
echo ($tag->title != 'D') ? $tag->title : '';
```

Or if you mean you want it to literally output the string "NOTHING", put that between the two single quotes.